# Using Knockout.JS and Google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I am fairly new with `Javascript` and even more so with `Knockout.JS`. I am currently trying to make a map that can be filtered by search results. i.e. search bar filters map markers and a list view. I had everything working correctly but now I want to move the map load out of the viewmodel.

I tried using a function to load the map just outside the `viewModel` but then it messed up all the other functionality. Any suggestions or best practices on getting the map load out of the viewModel and maintaining functionality. Thanks in advance. Here is what I have so far:

```
var koViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 15
  });

  self.allPlaces = [];
    locationList.forEach(function(place) {
      self.allPlaces.push(new Place(place));
  });

  self.allPlaces.forEach(function(place) {
    var markerOptions = {
      map: self.googleMap,
      position: place.latLng,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    };

    place.marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
  });

  self.visiblePlaces = ko.observableArray();

  self.allPlaces.forEach(function(place) {
    self.visiblePlaces.push(place);
  });

  self.userInput = ko.observable('');

  self.filterMarkers = function() {
    var searchInput = self.userInput().toLowerCase();

    self.visiblePlaces.removeAll();

    self.allPlaces.forEach(function(place) {
      place.marker.setMap(null);

      if (place.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInput) !== -1) {
        self.visiblePlaces.push(place);
      }
    });

    self.visiblePlaces().forEach(function(place) {
      place.marker.setMap(self.googleMap);
    });
  };

  function Place(dataObj) {
    this.name = dataObj.name;
    this.latLng = dataObj.latLng;
    this.marker = null;
  }

};

ko.applyBindings(new koViewModel());
```

Comment: Your snippet needs Knockout enabled.

Answer (score 9):

You could consider the following approach:

a)initialize the map once an HTML page is fully loaded

b)apply bindings and pass map object via `viewModel`

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){

    var locationList = [
       { name: 'New York', latLng: { lat: 40.786998, lng: -73.975664 } },
       { name: 'San Francisco', latLng: { lat: 37.763061, lng: -122.431935 } },
       { name: 'Los Angeles', latLng: { lat: 34.079078, lng: -118.242818 } }
    ];
    var googleMap = createMap();
    ko.applyBindings(new koViewModel(googleMap,locationList));

   });
```

**Example**

```js
var koViewModel = function(map,locationList) {
  var self = this;

  self.googleMap = map;

  self.allPlaces = [];
    locationList.forEach(function(place) {
      self.allPlaces.push(new Place(place));
  });

  self.allPlaces.forEach(function(place) {
    var markerOptions = {
      map: self.googleMap,
      position: place.latLng,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    };

    place.marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
  });

  self.visiblePlaces = ko.observableArray();

  self.allPlaces.forEach(function(place) {
    self.visiblePlaces.push(place);
  });

  self.userInput = ko.observable('');

  self.filterMarkers = function() {
    var searchInput = self.userInput().toLowerCase();

    self.visiblePlaces.removeAll();

    self.allPlaces.forEach(function(place) {
      place.marker.setMap(null);

      if (place.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInput) !== -1) {
        self.visiblePlaces.push(place);
      }
    });

    self.visiblePlaces().forEach(function(place) {
      place.marker.setMap(self.googleMap);
    });
  };

  function Place(dataObj) {
    this.name = dataObj.name;
    this.latLng = dataObj.latLng;
    this.marker = null;
  }
  
};




function createMap() {
    return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: 40.166294, lng: -96.389016 },
        zoom: 4
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){

    var locationList = [
       { name: 'New York', latLng: { lat: 40.786998, lng: -73.975664 } },
       { name: 'San Francisco', latLng: { lat: 37.763061, lng: -122.431935 } },
       { name: 'Los Angeles', latLng: { lat: 34.079078, lng: -118.242818 } }
    ];
    var googleMap = createMap();
    ko.applyBindings(new koViewModel(googleMap,locationList));

});
```

```css
   html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }


        #floating-panel {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 5%;
            z-index: 5;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
            line-height: 30px;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-debug.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>
  <div id="floating-panel">
        <b>Place: </b>
        <input data-bind="value: userInput" />
        <button data-bind="click: filterMarkers">Filter</button>
 </div>
 <div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help! Much more than I expected to receive. Would this still allow me to asynchronous load the google maps API by adding in the async keyword?

Comment: @BobyLight You chould have at least upvoted the answer if it were so helpful